# Can I print symbols in hex with more than 2 characters?

Tags: python-3.x

I am using Python 3.5.2

I know that with print("\x00") (where 0 is an ASCII character) I can print symbols with hex format. But how can I print number 500,000 (in hex: 7A120) when print("\x00") takes only 2 characters?

Comment: `hex(500000)` will produce `0x7a120` as a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To print a constant hexidecimal expression, you can prefix the number with a `0x`, and it will resolve to an `int` with the equivalent base 10 value, like so:

```
>>> print(0x7A120)
500000
```

If you want to print a string with arbitrary hexidecimal characters in it, use `int`:

```
>>> a = "7A120"
>>> print(int(a, 16))
500000
```

The second argument to `int` is the base to parse the string from, in this case base 16 (hex).

To print an integer in hexidecimal format, use the format operator, `%`:

```
>>> a = 0x7A120
>>> print("%x" % a)
7a120
```

You can change the "x" in "%x" to uppercase to print a through f in uppercase:

```
>>> b = 0xABCDEF
>>> print("%x" % b)
abcdef
>>> print("%X" % b)
ABCDEF
```